# passing events from parent to child react got undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Parent Class Component:**

```
toggleFunction = (event, ...otherProps) => {
    console.log(event) // EVENT GOT UNDEFINED
    console.log(otherProps) // THIS IS DISPLAYING WHAT IS NEED!
}

<Child updateFunction={(event) => this.toggleFunction(event,"PROPS-1","PROPS-2")}>
```

**Child Functional Component:**

```
const Child = ({ updateFunction }) => {
   ... OTHER CODE HERE
   <div onClick={() => updateFunction()}>Toggle</div>
}
```

My Problem is when i create event inside parent callback and pass to child as a method and execute parent *toggleFunction* in Parent Class. **ONLY THE EVENT GOT UNDEFINED, OTHER PROPS IS DISPLAYING CORRECTLY**

I found a solution by creating event inside child component and accessing inside Parent component, but that doesn't work for me as expected! Can anyone explain at what am i failing.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Can you post the part of code creating the event ?

Comment: It's a react event created during callback

Comment: I wanted to see what could trigger the event

Comment: Am not an expert in entire function i just know how to use it, somethings i don't know about how it works :( Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the event from `onClick` to `updateFunction`:

```
<div onClick={event => updateFunction(event)}>Toggle</div>
```

Or let `onClick` call it for you since the first parameter is the event:

```
<div onClick={updateFunction}>Toggle</div>
```

Comment: My question is why the otherProps is displaying what i need, why the event alone?

Comment: And there are other Props too?

Comment: In `(event) => this.toggleFunction(event,"PROPS-1","PROPS-2")` the `event` is `undefined` (since you call `updateFunction` with no parameters). The other props are fine so they are passed correctly.

Comment: Why the event alone got undefined, why not the others?

Comment: ```toggleFunction = (event, prop1,prop2) => { console.log(event,props1,props2)```. In this case to the event alone is undefined?

Comment: You set the remaining props in the parent component, but event is passed from the child ```onClick``` action.

Comment: Oh Got your point! Thanks a lot for taking time to explain!